# What is the Small "e" in Scientific Notation / Double in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numbers

when I calculate a very small number, matlab gives
`1.12345e-15`
What is this?
I can interpret it as 1.12345*10^(-15)
or its 1.12345*e^(-15)
I am in very hurry. Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: 'e' stands for the exponent. So your number would be 1.12345 * 10^(-15).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

e represents scientific notation as Rahul said but it is base 10, not base e.

Run the following code to confirm.

```
1e1
```

It gives you

```
ans = 10
```

Comment: Yeah I don't mean to steal the spotlight, but yeah it's base 10 with a bit more explanation and testing code

Answer (score 4):

e represents exponential. Its the [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) of writing numbers.

The base is 10. For example:

```
1e2 =100
1e-2= 0.01
```

Comment: exponential of what? 10 or e (natural number) ? <- This is the question

Comment: its not base 10 then?

Comment: @Tom:- I am really sorry, its base 10. Sorry for the confusion.